# arima concept clarification on differencing term d

Tags: arima, data-transformation, lags

I have a simple question regarding the d term in the arima(p,d,q).
I understand when d = 1, we are essentially differencing the time series by X(t)-X(t-1).
however I am confused when d=2 please help understand which of the following operation is done here:

1. X(t)-X(t-2)
   or
2. (X(t)-X(t-1))-(X(t-1)-X(t-2)) aka X(t)-2*X(t-1)+X(t-2)

Comment: The second one.

Comment: The first one is sometimes called seasonal differencing.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Ali

Comment: @AhmedAli, the first one is only called seasonal differencing if the seasonal frequency is 2. This is not a very typical number, unlike of 4 (quarterly), 12 (monthly), 7 (weekday), 24 (hourly) and other. Though what is typical depends on the field of application, of course.

Comment: @RichardHardy Good point; I think calling it lag-$2$ differencing would be more appropriate as done in Brockwell and Davis.